# node.js Error Callback Syntax

Tags: node.js

I'm a nodejs novice, and I'm looking for a little bit of guidance on style.  I've got a simple route, that's calling the **get** function defined below:

```
var gameSchema = new Schema({
ExecutableName : String,
Name : String,
});

var Game = mongoose.model('games', gameSchema );

var get = function( id, func ) {

    Game.findById( id )
        .exec( function( err, doc ) {
            if( err ) {
                func( err );
            } else {
                func( null, doc );
            }
    });
};
```

Syntactically, I believe the function can be re-written as:

```
var get = function( id, func ) {

    Game.findById( id )
        .exec( function( err, doc ) {
            func( err, doc );
    });
};
```

From a style standpoint, is one method preferred over the other?  For the sake of readability and reducing nesting, I like the second definition.  However, I'd like to track with the prevailing style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rewrite as:

```
var get = function( id, func ) {
    Game.findById( id )
        .exec( func );
};
```

I think it's easier to read this way.

Comment: Yep, if your callback is expecting the normal `function(err, results){}` pattern, passing it in directly like this saves you a lot of eyestrain.